# How to retrieve a single value?

Tags: java, sqlite

I need to get a single value from SQLite database. I have 2 tables connected in a multiple way and between them is a middle table. I need to get a value from the middle table, but I am always getting an error and don't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is the hashcode and error:

- ResultSet@12c6d7d2
- Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
  "org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet@12c6d7d2"

Here is the method:

```
public int stockProducts(String warehouse, String product){
        String sqlSelectStock = "select piw.Stock from ProductsInWarehouse as piw " +
                "where piw.idWarehouse in (select w.id from Warehouseas w " +
                "where w.nameWarehouse = '" + warehouse + "') " +
                "and piw.idProducts in (select p.id from Products as p " +
                "where p.nameProduct = '" + product + "');";
        ResultSet result = null;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            stmt = povezava.createStatement();
            result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectStock);
            count = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is a `ResultSet` object and not a String.
This `ResultSet` object contains the rows returned by the query that you execute.
You must loop (if you are expecting more than 1 rows) through the rows of `result` and extract the value of the column `Stock` so you can parse it to an `Integer`.
I assume (by your code) that you are expecting only 1 row, so change to this

```
stmt = povezava.createStatement();
result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectStock);
String stock = "0";
if (rs.next()) {
    stock = result.getString("Stock");
}
count = Integer.parseInt(stock);
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! :)